# Create a CustomUpdate Modal Dialog similar to LoginModal Popup in JHipster 5.0.0 or later version

Tags: modal-dialog, popup, angular5, jhipster, simplemodal

I am trying to implement an Update Modal Dialog similar to LoginModal Popup in JHipster 5.0.0 or later version.
I could not find much documentation.
Any steps, links or advice is greatly appreciated.
Thanks,

[image]
Please see the sample screen for details.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/jnizet/15c7a0ab4188c9ce6c79ca9840c71c4e) for creating modal like the LoginModal with ng-bootstrap .

Comment: My post was on JHipster generator and it's components. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Exactly, when you look at JhiLoginModalComponent, you will see  import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'; So my late  comment is  not out of your context.

Comment: you are correct and I noticed same. My idea was to follow JhiLoginModalComponent as a learning technic. I am less experienced with jhipster. I found  and followed this excellent article on 'Creating a Popup with Bootstrap and Angular' https://www.jeffryhouser.com/index.cfm/2017/11/2/Creating-a-Popup-with-Bootstrap-and-Angular-4

Answer (score 1):

I followed below blog post and implemented Custom Modal Dialog.
[Creating a Popup with Bootstrap and Angular](https://www.jeffryhouser.com/index.cfm/2017/11/2/Creating-a-Popup-with-Bootstrap-and-Angular-4)